# Order by reverse relationship count

Tags: craft3, relations, relatedto

It feels like I’m trying to do the impossible, but I can’t imagine this problem is unique to my project. Hoping someone here has figured it out before!

I have two channels, `creators` and `products`, and I can assign any number of `products` to a creator through a related entries field: `creatorProducts`.

How do I display the top 10 most popular products? Or, in other words, how do I sort the products by the number of creators they’ve been assigned to?

Haven’t been able to find the answer anywhere. Welp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have tons and tons of creators, you could do that by querying `creators` and re-arranging the results:

```twig
{# Get all creators and eager-load the products #}
{% set creators = craft.entries()
    .section('creators')
    .with('products')
    .all()
%}

{# Declare an array to store all related product ID #}
{% set products = [] %}

{# Build an array of all product ID occurences #}
{% for item in creators %}
    {% for product in item.products %}
        {% set products = products | merge([product.id]) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{# Group by product ID #}
{% set groupedProducts = products | group(v => v) %}

{# Sort by occurence count #}
{% set sortedGroupedProducts = groupedProducts | sort((a, b) => b <=> a)  %}

{# Now you can get: Product ID | Occurences #}
{% for c in sortedGroupedProducts | slice(0,10)%}
    Product ID: {{ c[0] }} | Occurences: {{ c|length }}<br>
{% endfor %}
<hr>
{# To fetch the products, extract the keys from the above and flatten to a comma seperated list of product IDs #}
{% set productIds = sortedGroupedProducts|keys|join(',') %}

{# Query #}
{% set products = craft.entries()
    .section('products')
    .id(productIds)
    .fixedOrder()
    .limit(10)
    .all() %}

{% for item in products %}
    {{ item.title }} ({{ sortedGroupedProducts[item.id] | length }})<br>
{% endfor %}
```

This could probably be improved or even moved to PHP but if you have to do in Twig, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for this great, detailed answer. Really appreciate it and does the trick indeed!