# Sorting Categories/Entries by # of relations dynamically

Tags: templating, relations

does anyone know if there's a way to display a type of "most popular categories" list? It's not exactly my use-case, but it's very similar

Essentially, I want to be able to have users search for elements with a certain number of relations. I saw an article about using Preparse but these are being maintained by front-end users and I don't want to have to wait for someone to save the parent element to have an accurate count.

Comment: Would this work for your case - https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/37188/3630 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit brute-force but you can loop all the elements and then check their related count:

```
{% for row in craft.entries.section('foo').all() %}
   {% if row.myRelatedField.count() == 10 %}
      <li>{{ row.title }}</li>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You may want to eager-load myRelatedField to save an expensive database query.